# Why did Cardfight Vanguard only change the OP Music but not the Animation?

Tags: music, cardfight-vanguard

Around after Team Q4 lost the National Tournament (Episode 33) the OP for the series changed to feature a new Song, but with the Hanabee release (English Sub and Dub, actually watching the Sub rather than the Dub) it seems the subtitles were hard subs into the footage and thus you see a disconnect with what's on screen and what's in the song (ie. words appearing when there are no words in the song, clearly different words)

But why change the OP's music but leave the animation? if it was to cut cost on redoing the OP's animation wouldn't it then be argued it would have been better to keep the original OP's Music than change it?

Comment: Just speculation; their contract with the musicians was to only have their song be used for X episodes and the contract wasn't renewed. Some animes are rewritten at short notice; maybe the season went on longer than anticipated.

Comment: For those who don't follow the series, could you provide some episode numbers for references? On the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardfight!!_Vanguard#English_dub) has info about the OPs and EDs used for the English dubbed version, but without knowing why...

Comment: @AkiTanaka sorry, it was roughly episode 33. also going by the info on wikipedia i think it might be the third OP's music (Limit Break) that might be playing but will have to double check the OP credits